# Set correct start time of ts-file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am splitting up a video into multiple 10 second ts-parts (mpeg-ts format) using ffmpeg on windows.

To create the 2nd part (that starts at 10 seconds into the video and ends at 20 seconds into the video):

```
ffmpeg -i sample.avi -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -vf scale=426:-1 out1.ts
```

But when i check the file using ffprobe it says:

```
Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 1.458667, bitrate: 359 kb/s
```

So the duration is ok but the start time is incorrect. Is it anyway i can use ffmpeg to correct it to 00:00:20?
The best solution would of course to be able to set the correct start time in my first command where i take out the 10 second part but i would also be ok with running a 2nd command to fix the time.

Is this possible? Cant find any documentation and all examples i found are not for my exact problem and don't seem to work then i play around with them.

Full output from ffprobe:

```
ffprobe.exe out1.ts
ffprobe version git-2020-02-06-343ccfc Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 39.100 / 56. 39.100
  libavcodec     58. 68.100 / 58. 68.100
  libavformat    58. 38.100 / 58. 38.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 74.100 /  7. 74.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'out1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 1.458667, bitrate: 359 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 426x260 [SAR 780:781 DAR 18:11], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `-muxdelay 10` argument.

**Update:** As jarno commented, add: `-muxdelay 10 -muxpreload 10`

I found the solution [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/26364/how-to-change-start-time-using-ffmpeg).

Using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i sample.avi -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -vf scale=426:-1 -muxdelay 10 out1.ts
```

I am getting the following result from `ffprobe`:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'out1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:10.05, start: 20.020222, bitrate: 141 kb/s
```

---

I used the following commands for testing:

- Generating AVI sample file with synthetic video and synthetic audio (in uncompressed raw format):

  ```
   ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=30 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=500 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -t 30 sample.avi
  ```
- Executing the command from your question and `ffprobe` (I added `-y` for overwriting the output):

  ```
   ffmpeg -y -i sample.avi -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -vf scale=426:-1 -muxdelay 10 out1.ts
   ffprobe out1.ts
  ```

---

### Update:

As jarno commented, adding `-muxpreload 10` is also necessary.
For cleaner solution add: `-muxdelay 10 -muxpreload 10`

Command example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i sample.avi -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -vf scale=426:-1 -muxdelay 10 -muxpreload 10 out1.ts
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried you commands and they worked for your sample file but not for my video? I tried to download a free video here (https://pixabay.com/videos/plant-leaves-wind-nature-macro-26637/) and then i ran the command with -muxdelay 10 (ffmpeg -y -i "Plant - 26637.mp4" -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -vf scale=426:-1 -muxdelay 10 out1.ts).   But i still get start time of 1.45.... ?

Comment: That's weird, I downloaded the same version of `FFmpeg` (git-2020-02-06-343ccfc), and the same video file `Plant - 26637.mp4`, and executed the same command, and I am getting 'Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 20.080000, bitrate: 643 kb/s'. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried on another computer and it worked. I tried on the latest stable build and that one worked on my computer. I should not have used the nightly build, i missed that that was the version i downloaded. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The solution you refer to uses `-muxpreload`, too. Documentation says it sets "the initial demux-decode delay" whereas `-muxdelay` is "the maximum demux-decode delay".  Could you use the former alternatively?